# PHP Associative Array Duplicate Keys

Tags: php

I have an associative array, however when I add values to it using the below function it seems to overwrite the same keys. Is there a way to have multiple of the same keys with different values? Or is there another form of array that has the same format?

I want to have:

```
42=>56
42=>86
42=>97
51=>64
51=>52
etc etc
```

Code:

```
   function array_push_associative(&$arr) {
       $args = func_get_args();
       foreach ($args as $arg) {
           if (is_array($arg)) {
               foreach ($arg as $key => $value) {
                   $arr[$key] = $value;
                   $ret++;
               }
           }else{
               $arr[$arg] = "";
           }
       }
       return $ret;
    }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of these numeric keys?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array.

You could, however, have unique keys each of whose corresponding values are arrays, and those arrays have multiple elements for each key.

So instead of this...

```
42=>56 42=>86 42=>97 51=>64 51=>52
```

...you have this:

```
Array (
    42 => Array ( 56, 86, 97 )
    51 => Array ( 64, 52 )
)
```

Answer (score 8):

A key is an extension of a variable. If you overwrite the variable... You overwrite the variable.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot have. A workaround I use is to have each key/value pair as a new array with 2 elements:

```
$test = array(
     array(42,56),
     array(42,86),
     array(42,97),
     array(51,64),
     array(51,52)
)
```

For example, you can access the second key (=42) using:

```
$test[1][0]
```

and the second value(=86) using:

```
 $test[1][1]
```

Comment: while the end result of the var assignment can't show multiple keys, you may still define them at definition time. Example:
`$mytab = array('a' => 'valA', 'b' => 'valB', 'a' => 'anotherValA');`
The behaviour to expect then is that the _last who speaks is right_. You would end up with this array:
`{ a => anotherValA, b => valB}`

Comment: @FabienHaddadi what is the reason to do this, since the first will be overwritten by the second? this is an intentional bug.

Comment: no valid reason! Bad practice. It's just possible, period :-) I just fixed that in my Client's code a few hours ago...

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while researching the exact opposite intended outcome, I have an array of data that has duplicate keys! Here's how I did it (still trying to figure out where in my process things are messing up).

```
$session = time();
$a = array();
$a[(string)$session] = 0;
$j = json_encode($a,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print_r($a);
/* output:
Array
(
    [1510768034] => 0
)
*/
var_dump($a);
/* output:
array(1)
(
    [1510768034] =>   int(0)
)
*/
print_r($j);
/* output:
{"1510768034":0}
*/
$a = (array)json_decode($j);
$session = @array_pop(array_keys($a));
$a[(string)$session] = 10;
$j = json_encode($a,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
print_r($a);
/* output:
Array
(
    [1510768034] => 0
    [1510768034] => 10
)
*/
var_dump($a);
/* output:
array(2)
(
    '1510768034' => int(0)
    [1510768034] => int(10)
)
*/
print_r($j);
/* output:
{"1510768034":0,"1510768034":10}
*/
```

Yup....that just happened.

PHP 7.1

Edit: It's similar in PHP 7.2.10, except json_encode no longer entertains duplicate keys, encoded strings are correct.  The array, however, can have matching string and integer keys.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same need too create an array with the same keys, (just to keep performance by using two loops rather than 4 loops).

by using this :  [$increment."-".$domain_id] => $article_id;
my list of articles in each domain looks like this after a print_r() :

```
$AllSa  = Array
(
    [1-5] => 143
    [2-5] => 176
    [3-5] => 992
    [4-2] => 60
    [5-2] => 41
    [6-2] => 1002
    [4-45] => 5
    [5-45] => 18
    [6-45] => 20
)
```

And then by looping through this table to associate article by domain :

```
$AssocSAPerDomain = array();
    $TempDomain       = "";
    $TempDomain_first = 0;
    foreach($tree_array as $id_domain => $id_sa){
        if( !$TempDomain && $TempDomain_first == 0 ){  $TempDomain = substr(strrchr($id_domain, "-"), 1); $TempDomain_first = 1; }
        $currentDomain = substr(strrchr($id_domain, "-"), 1);
        //if($TempDomain == $currentDomain) 
        $AssocSAPerDomain[$currentDomain][] = $id_sa;
        $TempDomain = substr(strrchr($id_domain, "-"), 1);
    }
```

you get this

```
$assoc= Array
(
    [5] => 143
        => 176
        => 992
    [2] => 60
        => 41
        => 1002
    [45]=> 5
        => 18
        => 20
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible technically. But I created a fun way to do it. Be alert, this answer is just for the fun, the ultimate goal is to get the output anyway.

So here is the answer. You first need to convert to the whole array to the string. Then the rest of the things is just string replace and a little code.

```
<?php

$ary="array('a'=>123,'a'=>161,'a'=>195)";

$str = str_replace("array(", "", $ary);
$str = str_replace(")", "", $str);
$arr = explode(",",$str);

foreach($arr as $element){
    $element = str_replace("=>", "", $element);
    $element = str_replace("'", "", $element);

    echo $element.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Here is the output
[image]

Comment: After seeing your solution... I'm really confused should I give it a up vote or not !  :v

Comment: @fahim152 ha ha. it is up to you. I just showed a way to do it for an emergency purpose. Because technicaly it is not possible but if you are in a crital situation and really wanted to do it anyway, then this is for you. Thanks