# How should I sort this array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to implement a messaging functionality in my system. My goal right now is having a jQuery popup dialog which displays the name of users that have messaged the other person and then clicking on that person's name will show the new messages. I've done the popup dialog bit so my next step is getting and sorting the messages from database.

What I've done now is retrieve the new messages from database. I am unsure of how to proceed as my array of unread messages contains the element of the sender's id more than once. I do not want to loop through my unread messages and then get the same sender id again and again and as such retrieve their details from database again and again.

Here's an example of my array:

```
array(8) {
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "52"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "330"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(10) "test"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336561645"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "53"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "330"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(8) "bye"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336561648"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "329"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(243) "Hi Bob"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1330942044"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "243"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1335517653"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "46"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(8) "sdsdfsdf"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336139572"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "47"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(13) "8528528285285"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336143958"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
array(8) {
  [6]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "52"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "330"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(10) "test"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336561645"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "53"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "330"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(8) "bye"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336561648"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "329"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(243) "Hi Bob"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1330942044"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "243"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1335517653"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "46"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(8) "sdsdfsdf"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336139572"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "47"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(13) "8528528285285"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336143958"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "138"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(54) "Hi Emma thank you for submitting your homework - Jenny"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1309122193"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
}
```

This is what I've done in PHP so far:

```
$m = new Messaging();
$json = $m->getUnreadMessages($uid);

/** sort messages by useridfrom **/
uasort($json, array($m, 'messageCompare'));

foreach($json as $j)
{
 //do sorting of messages here ??
}


echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

I guess ideally, I would want to create a new array out of this where the key is useridfrom (sender) and then their messages and then associated with each message the timecreated. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As you can see from the array example there are duplicate useridfrom elements where useridfrom = 241 twice. This means that the user 241 has sent two messages, if there were 3 useridfrom 241 elements then that means he/she sent 3 messages. My goal is two group the useridfrom together as keys in an array so there are no duplicates then associated with that key we have all their messages (message) and the time the message was created (timecreated).

```
 [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "46"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(8) "sdsdfsdf"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336139572"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "47"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "241"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(13) "8528528285285"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1336143958"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }

 [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["useridfrom"]=>
    string(3) "329"
    ["useridto"]=>
    string(3) "139"
    ["message"]=>
    string(243) "Hi Bob"
    ["format"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["timecreated"]=>
    string(10) "1330942044"
    ["messagetype"]=>
    string(6) "direct"
  }
```

So from this example, it should lead to an array of something like what mariomario has suggested:

```
array{
  ['241'] => array(
   [0] => array(time=>'time1', message => "hello i am 241"),
   [1] => array(time=>'time2', message => "nice to meet you"),
),
['330'] => array(
       [0] => array(time=>'time1', message => "hello i am 330"),
       [1] => array(time=>'time2', message => "goodbye"),
    )
}
```

Comment: If your database is SQL-backed: why don't you sort directly in your query, like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY useridfrom ASC, timecreated DESC`?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. 

Would that not still give me duplicate useridfrom elements?

Comment: You're right... check my answer below then ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

After a little pondering I'd do this:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($json as $j) {
    if (!array_key_exists($j['useridfrom'], $data)) {
        $data[$j['useridfrom']] = array();
    }
    if (!array_key_exists($j['useridto'], $data[$j['useridfrom']])) {
        $data[$j['useridfrom']][$j['useridto']] = array();
    }
    $data[$j['useridfrom']][$j['useridto']][] = array(
        'message' => $j['message'],
        'timestamp' => $j['timecreated']  
    );
}
```

Keep your data ordered like so `ORDER BY timecreated DESC` and that concats everything like you want ordered after the time.

This should net an array like so:

```
'sender1' => (
    'recipient1' = (
        (
            'message' => 'MESSAGE HERE',
            'timecreated' => 'TIME HERE'
        ),
        (
            'message' => 'ANOTHER MESSAGE HERE',
            'timecreated' => 'ANOTHER TIME HERE'
        )
    ),
    'recipient2' = (
        (
            'message' => 'MESSAGE HERE',
            'timecreated' => 'TIME HERE'
        )
    )
),
'sender2' => (
)
```

Comment: Ah, I just see it's basically what mariomario did, but with the `if` statement. So +1 to him I guess.

Comment: Yeah we're progressing now! But then we run into the next problem of duplicate keys which mariomario was pointing out. My final goal is to have an array similar to that but with multiple arrays of message,time associated with the sender because naturally, a sender can send more than one message.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Check out if that is what you're after, please.

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't take into account of the duplicate keys and thereby not adding the other messages for 241 :S I think it's the last statement in the for loop because we're overwriting it if it exists i.e. if none of the conditions are met in the if statement

Comment: It shouldn't overwrite anything. The last line `$data[$j['useridfrom']][$j['useridto']][] = 'value';` adds a new value to the existing array (that's what the empty `[]` is for, it's more or less a shortcut for `array_push`). Have you tried the code or are you only assuming it's not working!?

Comment: ahh nevermind ignore what I said. It works! The one before your last edit works as well so we don't need useridto. Thank you :)

Comment: It was working. All those values in my array just confused me =p

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't you do something like this

```
$newArray = array()

foreach($json as $j)
{
 $array[$j['useridfrom']][] = array('time'=>$j['timecreated'],
'message'=>$j[message]);
}
```

they you will have a array like this:

```
array{
  ['user1'] => array(
   [0] => array(time=>'time1', message => message1),
   [1] => array(time=>'time2', message => message2),
),
['user2'] => array(
       [0] => array(time=>'time1', message => message1),
       [1] => array(time=>'time2', message => message2),
    )
}
```

but maybe I am understanding you not correct.

Comment: Hey that is the potential array that I would like to achieve but would that not also give me duplicate useridfrom keys? 

For example, in my original array I will get useridfrom => 241,  useridfrom =>241 twice because the user from id = 241 message the other person twice.

Comment: I'm thinking about having if statement to check the previous useridfrom, if it was the same then continue inserting into new array but obviously what do we if it isn't the same and what do we do with the first check since there is no previous id to check?

Comment: Hmm I this will clear something up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key the keys can't be dublicates so a message with time and the message will be appended

Comment: Ah yes, I do not want the keys to be duplicate so perhaps an if statement to check if they are the same, if so then add another array(time, message) to that key.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_multisort in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php