# AND in an array?

Tags: php

So I have an array

```
$date1 = "12/31/12";
$date2 = "01/01/13";

$a = array(
            'all' => true,
            'upcoming'=>true,
            'date'=>$date1,
            //'date'=>$date2,
            'is_nye'=>true,
            'where'=>$where,
            'status'=>'A'
        );
```

And I want to check if the query has both dates how would I go about that? As I know if I add it in its current state it will display only date2 as it takes place of the original date.

Comment: Your query seems to be missing.

Comment: Are you using this to generate an SQL query?  Can you please explain a bit more about what you're doing as it is not clear?

Comment: As others have mentioned, you either need to use different keys or modify the data structure - it's hard to say which is better w/o seeing how you're going to build your query (or even better, the underlying table in the DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name the keys differently:

```
$a = array(
    'all' => true,
    'upcoming'=>true,
    'date_1'=>$date1,
    'date_2'=>$date2,
    'is_nye'=>true,
    'where'=>$where,
    'status'=>'A'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are trying to build an array with duplicate keys, which can not be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879138/665261

As there is no way to store the array you are trying to store (with duplicate keys) there is of course no way to retrieve the values.

The answer is to use a different data structure, or rename the keys to be unique.

I think what I would do, is make `date` an array in itself, so something like...

```
    $a = array(
        'all' => true,
        'upcoming'=>true,
        'date'=>array(
             $date1,
             $date2
        ),
        'is_nye'=>true,
        'where'=>$where,
        'status'=>'A'
    );
```

Comment: Why is this the best way to go? Now there is no context to date1 or date2, and the dev will have to know which element of the multi-dim array contains the correct date value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$a = array(
            'all' => true,
            'upcoming'=>true,
            'date1'=>$date1,
            'date2'=>$date2,
            'is_nye'=>true,
            'where'=>$where,
            'status'=>'A'
        );
```

And to construct the query, do this:

```
if($a['date2']){

    $query .= "AND date2 = '" . $a['date2'] . "'";

}
```