# Removing duplicates from array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Have the following array with this data.
How can i only show every person once and then the first activity for every person.
I could use the array_unique() function but this also removing the Activity duplicates.
I only need to remove the duplicates of the persons.

```
mainArray = array(
'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'abc', 
'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'cba',
'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'abc',
'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'cba',
'person' => '3', 'Activity' => 'cba');
```

I want this result:

```
person 1 - Activity abc
person 2 - Activity abc
person 3 - Activity cba
```

Sorry My array look like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Person] => 1 [Activity] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Person] => 1 [Activity] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Person] => 2 [Activity] => 1 )
```

Comment: Your code looks wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key How you get this array? It is not properly formatted array...

Comment: sectus> What do you mean?

Comment: You cannot have two or more values with the same key. Only the last key value pair will be stored.

Comment: also if i do the array in a while where i add data to the array?

Comment: check my answer stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if your array is like this

```
  $mainArray = Array
   (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [person] => 1
          [Activity] => abc
        )

    [1] => Array
       (
          [person] => 1
          [Activity] => cba
       )

    [2] => Array
       (
          [person] => 2
          [Activity] => abc
       )

    [3] => Array
       (
          [person] => 2
          [Activity] => cba
       )

    [4] => Array
       (
          [person] => 3
          [Activity] => cba
       )
)
```

Then here is the Solution for you:

```
$unique_array = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($mainArray as $array){
 $insert = false;
 if(!empty($unique_array)){
    foreach($unique_array as $u){

        if($u['person'] != $array['person'])
            $insert = true;
        else
            $insert = false;
    }//End of Foreach
 }else
    $insert = true;
 if($insert){
    $unique_array[$count]['person'] = $array['person'];
    $unique_array[$count]['Activity'] = $array['Activity'];
    $count++;
 }
}
```

Comment: How can I echo the result? print_r($mainArray); ?

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($mainArray);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique_array);
echo "</pre>";

That will show you the two formatted arrays, put it at the end of code

Comment: Thx boom_Shiva :-) Sorry for my bad explanation in the first post.

Comment: Ya I already considered that you must have made a mistake in typing the array here So i explained my answer this way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two or more values with the same key; if two keys are the same, how can you access the value of one individual key alone?

```
<?php

$mainArray = array(
'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'abc', 
'person' => '1', 'Activity' => 'cba',
'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'abc',
'person' => '2', 'Activity' => 'cba',
'person' => '3', 'Activity' => 'cba');

print_r($mainArray);
?>
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
Array ( [person] => 3 [Activity] => cba )
// Only the last unique key-value pair is stored in the array
```

So, you might want to store the values in a format similar to this:

```
$mainArray = array(
    'person'   => array('1',  '1',  '2',  '2',   '3'),
    'Activity' => array('abc','cba','abc','cba','cba')
    );
```

This makes you easier to get the corresponding values (`Activity`) for the `person`, too.