# How to add same key values in an associative array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$result  = array(
  'a' => 15,
  'b' => 25,
  'a' => 10,
  'c' => 6,
  'k' => 10
);
```

I need the sum of same key values.
i.e. output like:

```
  $result  = array(
  'a' => 25,
  'b' => 25,
  'c' => 6,
  'k' => 10
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate? If the array already has the same key you cannot add it again - only replace the value

Comment: What do you need? It's really unclear.

Comment: i mean get sum of same key value in this array..

Comment: Please edit you question and show us a desired result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Associative Array Duplicate Key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key)

Comment: same key not possible, you can add sub array if values multiple `array('a' => array(10, 20, 30))`

Comment: Same key values or different ?Please explain

Comment: ie i need to get result as $result  = array(
  'a' => 25,
  'b' => 25,
  'c' => 6,
  'k' => 10
);

Comment: You can't have an array that matches your original with two keys called `a`..... what do you actually have?

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible, in an associative array the keys are unique by definition. It wouldn't be quite associative otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple same keys in an array. If you want multiple keys in the same array you should create a multidimensional array:

```
$result  = array();

$result[KEY1 (or empty)] = array(
  'a' => 15,
  'b' => 25,
  'c' => 6,
  'k' => 10
);

$result[KEY2 (or empty)] = array(
  'a' => 15,
  'b' => 25,
  'c' => 6,
  'k' => 10
);
```

If you want the sum of the same key's you can use something like this:

```
function getSum($key, $array)
{
    $sum = 0;

    foreach($result as $array)
    {
        if( array_key_exists($key, $array) && is_numeric($array[$key]) )
        {
            $sum += $array[$key];
        }
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

So with this function you can call:

```
$sum = getSum('a', $result);
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Didn't even saw. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object? If you add logic to adding values, you won't need some fancy `foreach()` loops to calculate the sum ([demo](http://codepad.org/iuyxNiPf))

```
class UniqueList {

    private $data = array();

    public function insert($key, $value) {
        if (isSet($this->data[$key]))
            $this->data[$key] += $value;
        else
            $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getAll() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$result = new UniqueList();
$result->insert('a', 5);
$result->insert('b', 15);
$result->insert('c', 25);

$result->insert('a', 23);
```