# Always getting last value of array

Tags: php, arrays

Why am I getting always the last value from the array? I'm stuck on what I'm doing wrong.

Please help! :p

```
$array = array("id"=>"4", "id"=>"5", "id"=>"6");
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $screenshots[] = $value;
}
var_dump($screenshots);
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2879132/3933332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rizier said, your keys in an associative array cannot have the same name.
This should work:

```
$array = array("id1"=>"4", "id2"=>"5", "id3"=>"6");

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        $screenshots[] = $value;

    }

var_dump($screenshots);
```