# How loop this array with while or foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this array

```
$data = array(
"id" => "1",
"code" => "5",
"name" => "AAA",
"id" => "2",
"code" => "6",
"name" => "VVV",
"id" => "3",
"code" => "7",
"name" => "DDD"
);
```

and i try use looping code with `foreach` like this

```
foreach($data as $x=>$rows)
{
     $tmpdata['alphabet'][$x] =  $rows;
}
```

and i want to get the output like this:

```
[alphabet] => Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [code] => 5
        [name] => AAA
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [code] => 6
        [name] => VVV
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [code] => 7
        [name] => DDD
    )
)
```

I tried to use looping method like `foreach` or `while` but not get the output as above.

Comment: Initial array is invalid. You **can't** have same keys in array.

Comment: you `data array` should be multi dimensional array.

Comment: so any solution? because the current output is running now but using while and obtained from the data base, in this case the array not through a database but manually.

Comment: There is no solution, because your initial array is invalid. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key

Comment: it will give u only one result, because of invalid array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to change your array as like:

```
$data = array(
            array("id"=>"1","code"=>"5","name"=>"AAA"),
            array("id"=>"2","code"=>"6","name"=>"VVV"),
            array("id"=>"3","code"=>"7","name"=>"DDD")
        );
```

Than you can solve this as:

```
$newArr['alphabet'] = $data;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Second Solution**, If you want to start INDEX from 1 instead of 0 than you can use as:

```
$newArr = array();
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $newArr['alphabet'][$i] = $value;   
    $i++;
}
```

**Result of First Solution:**

```
Array
(
    [alphabet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [code] => 5
                    [name] => AAA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [code] => 6
                    [name] => VVV
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => DDD
                )    
        )    
)
```

**Result of Second Solution:**

```
Array
(
    [alphabet] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [code] => 5
                    [name] => AAA
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [code] => 6
                    [name] => VVV
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [code] => 7
                    [name] => DDD
                )    
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid `array`

Change from

```
$data = array("id"=>"1","code"=>"5","name"=>"AAA","id"=>"2","code"=>"6",
               "name"=>"VVV","id"=>"3","code"=>"7","name"=>"DDD");
```

into

```
$data = array(
    array("id"=>"1","code"=>"5","name"=>"AAA"),
    array("id"=>"2","code"=>"6","name"=>"VVV"),
    array("id"=>"3","code"=>"7","name"=>"DDD")

);
```

then you can use `foreach`

```
foreach($data as $x=>$rows)
{
     $tmpdata['alphabet'][$x] =  $rows;
}
print_r($tmpdata); // Print Array
```

**OR**

In short you can get you desire output like this

```
$data['alphabet'][] = array("id"=>"1","code"=>"5","name"=>"AAA");
$data['alphabet'][] = array("id"=>"2","code"=>"6","name"=>"VVV");
$data['alphabet'][] = array("id"=>"3","code"=>"7","name"=>"DDD");

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a multidimensional array:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "id"=>"1",
        "code"=>"5",
        "name"=>"AAA"
    ),
    array(
        "id"=>"2",
        "code"=>"6",
        "name"=>"VVV"
    ),
    array(
        "id"=>"3",
        "code"=>"7",
        "name"=>"DDD"
    )  
);

foreach($data as $x => $rows){
    $tmpdata['alphabet'][$x] =  $rows;
}

var_dump($tmpdata);
```