# PHP Multidimensional Array with multiple array with same keys?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, soap-client

I've been trying multiple things and for the life of me can not get this to work. I'm beginning to think it maybe isn't possible at this point.

So I have a SOAP API I'm sending this array too. Below is the code I currently have that works, but does not send the multiple values. It just uses the last one as it overwrite the previous.

Looking at [this thread](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?191583-Why-can-t-an-array-contain-duplicate-keys&s=46ac551aa90f2364095da30a7469f58a&p=932713#post932713), what I'm doing should work?

```
$my_array['sn'] = "234234232";
$my_array['arrayparams'] = array(
'Param' => array( 'Name' =>     'sending_key', 'Value' => 'blah',), 
'Param' => array( 'Name' => 'sending_key2', 'Value' => '2',),
);
$my_array['push'] = true; 
$my_array['endsession'] = false;
```

returns:

```
array(4) {
  ["sn"]=>
  string(12) "234234232"
  ["arrayparams"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Param"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(61) "sending_key2"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  ["push"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["endsession"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I'm just having a time getting it to send this instead:

```
array(4) {
  ["sn"]=>
  string(12) "234234232"
  ["arrayparams"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Param"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(61) "sending_key"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(1) "blah"
    }
    ["Param"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(61) "sending_key2"
      ["Value"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  ["push"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["endsession"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

The 'Param' array is very strict and has to have this value, I can not change to 'Param2' to get it to work. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Associative Array Duplicate Key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key)

Comment: It's not possible to have duplicate keys in an associative array, it makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, but the API requires it to be sent this way which blew my mind.

Comment: I suspect you're misreading the API documentation. Got a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can't have the key 'Param' set in more than one key.

You would need to define 'Param' as an actual array, instead of as multiple keys within in array.

like so...

```
$my_array['Param'] = [
    ['Name' => 'sending_key', 'Value' => 'blah'],
    ['Name' => 'sending_key2', 'Value' => '2']
];
```

Comment: Up votes for this one, perfect solution! Thanks Mike!

Comment: please accept as solution if this works for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

can you do this?

```
$my_array['arrayparams'] = array(
    array('Param' => array( 'Name' =>     'sending_key', 'Value' => 'blah',)), 
    array('Param' => array( 'Name' => 'sending_key2', 'Value' => '2',)),
);
```

Comment: But obviously it's the right answer, because user1628515 wrote "perfect solution" to the answer of Mike, who basically sent the same answer