# Array merge NO (+) UNION or merge()

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array1 = [ "month" => "Jan", "count" => "20" , "month" => "feb", "count" => "2" ];
$array2 = [ "month" => "Jan", "count" => "50" , "month" => "feb", "count" => "27" ];
```

Expected array after merge the above 2 arrays

```
$fianlarray = ["month" => "jan" , "count"=>"20" , "count" => "50" , 
               "month" => "feb" , "count" => "2", "count" => "27" ];
```

i've tried array_merge and union but no result. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think there is issue in how you storing data. You cannot use same key twice inside array at same level, this will result in overwriting old data.

$array1 = [ "month" => "Jan", "count" => "20" , "month" => "feb", "count" => "2" ];
$array2 = [ "month" => "Jan", "count" => "50" , "month" => "feb", "count" => "27" ];

Here in your code you are storing 'month' as 'jan' then 'month' as 'feb', this is overwrite the previous assignment of 'month' => 'jan'.

Please restructure how you storing info inside array.

Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-key). Nicely explained by [amber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148870/amber).

If more help needed, I'm happy to help.

Thanks, Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we can not do as you mentioned in your question, you can not use same associative key again, in this case repeated associative key overrides value

```
$fianlarray = ["month" => "jan" , "count"=>"20" , "count" => "50" , 
               "month" => "feb" , "count" => "2", "count" => "27" ];
```

I suggest you to do good structure like below

```
$fianlarray = [["month" => "jan" , "count"=>["20", "50"]], 
               ["month" => "feb" , "count" => ["2","27"]]];
```

OR

```
$fianlarray = ["jan"=>["20", "50"],"feb"=>["2","27"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Aravindh Gopi You can not get array like you want because array can
>   not have same name index more than one, if you will do this so array
>   will overwrite the values and in this case $array1 values will be over
>   written by $array2 value and your will get your final array like:
>
> $fianlarray = ["month" => "feb",
>   "count" => "27" ];

But if you want your solution so you can do it with the function array_merge_recursive(), this function will give you, your solution but you will get the same index values in an new array with 0 and 1 index try below one:

```
<?php
    $array1 = [ "month" => "Jan", "count" => "20"];
    $array2 = ["month" => "feb", "count" => "27" ];
    $fianlarray=array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
    print_r($fianlarray);
?>
```

OutPut will be:

> Array ( [month] => Array ( [0] => Jan [1] => feb ) [count] => Array (
>   [0] => 20 [1] => 27 ) )

So try if your need is this (y)

Comment: Yeap i tried that array_merge_recursive() , but that's  not what i want mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such a thing :

```
$fianlarray = ["month" => "jan" , "count"=>"20" , "count" => "50" , 
               "month" => "feb" , "count" => "2", "count" => "27" ];
```

here you define multiple times the keys "month","count" which is forbidden...