# Adding values on array n PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a null array and I want to put a value on it to be like this.

```
$array = {[11 => 100, 11 => 100, 11 => 100]};
```

Now I have this code:

```
$array = array();
... // there is a 3 loop to call/add the array
array_push($array,[11 => 100]); 
print_r(array),
```

result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [11] => 100 ) [1] => Array ( [11] => 100 ) [2] => Array ( [11] => 100 ) )
```

I was expecting to be : `Array([11] => 100, [11] => 100, [11] => 100)`

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Associative Array Duplicate Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple of the same key in PHP. Additionally, you cannot push values onto arrays with `array_push` and specify keys at the same time.

You will need to rethink your data format.