# explode array into associative array which already exploded in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have string as

```
SportId : 56,GroundType : Public,SelectArea : 10,Cost : 3000-4000 ,Size : 7 * 7
```

when explode this array output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => SportId : 56
    [1] => GroundType : Public
    [2] => SelectArea : 10
    [3] => Cost : 3000-4000 
    [4] => Size : 7 * 7
)
```

I want output in associative array as

```
 Array
(
    ['SportId'] => 56
    ['GroundType'] => Public
    ['SelectArea'] => 10
    ['Cost'] => 3000-4000 
    ['Size'] => 7 * 7
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
<?php

$info = "SportId : 56,GroundType : Public,SelectArea : 10,Cost : 3000-4000 ,Size : 7 * 7";
$arrInfo = explode(",",$info);

$newArray = [];
foreach($arrInfo as $item) {
    $values = explode(":",$item);
    $newArray[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: An array is not supposed to have duplicate keys. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys

Comment: but I need to store both values as I want to pass them into sql where condition

Comment: If by both values you mean the key and the value you can do a: foreach($item as $key => $value) and get them.