# Reform PHP associated array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array:

```
    $input = [
        ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'a'],
        ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'b'],
        ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'c'],
        ['key'=>'y', 'value'=>'d'],
        ['key'=>'y', 'value'=>'e'],
        ['key'=>'z', 'value'=>'f'],
        ['key'=>'m', 'value'=>'n'],
    ];
```

And I want to reform it simple in:

```
    $output = [
        'x'=>['a','b','c'],
        'y'=>['d','e'],
        'z'=>'f',
        'm'=>'n'
    ]
```

So basically, conditions are:

```
1. If same key found then put values in an array.
2. If no same key found then value remains string.
```

You can replace associative array with object if you are more comfortable with objects.

Here is my working solution for this problem:

```
    foreach($input as $in){
        if(!empty($output[$in['key']])){
            if(is_array($output[$in['key']])){
                $output[$in['key']][] = $in['value'];
                continue;
            }
            $output[$in['key']] = [$output[$in['key']],$in['value']];
            continue;
        }
        $output[$in['key']] = $in['value'];
    }
    print_r($output);
```

However I believe that it can be done in much compact and efficient way.
Please comment your answers if someone has better solution.
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is your input an array?

Comment: yes, as shown in question, its an associative array.

Comment: Assume that `'x'=>'f',` in the result should be `'z'=>'f',`

Comment: You can't have duplicates with same key in array. Other 'key' value will overwrite old one.

Comment: Just what @AgniusVasiliauskas said, this is why I was surprised. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys explains that I think.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not in it's current form. Please take a look at the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/185143/52915)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reformat array to [ [ x=>a ], [x=>b],.. ] and merge all sub-arrays

```
$input = array_map(function($x) { return [$x['key'] => $x['value']]; }, $input);
$input = array_merge_recursive(...$input);
print_r($input);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/935029)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

```
<?php

$input = [
    ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'a'],
    ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'b'],
    ['key'=>'x', 'value'=>'c'],
    ['key'=>'y', 'value'=>'d'],
    ['key'=>'y', 'value'=>'e'],
    ['key'=>'z', 'value'=>'f'],
    ['key'=>'m', 'value'=>'n'],
];

$reducer = function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['key']][] = $item['value'];

    return $carry;
};

$mapper = function ($item) {
    if (count($item) === 1) {
        return $item[0];
    }

    return $item;
};

$output = array_map($mapper, array_reduce($input, $reducer, []));

var_dump($output);
```

You can see the result here: https://3v4l.org/8JjjS

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to loop over an existing array and build up a new one:

```
$output = array_reduce($input, function ($carry, $i) { 
  $carry[$i['key']][] = $i['value'];
  return $carry;
}, []);
```

Each element in `$input` is passed to the anonymous function, along with the `$carry` variable that's being built up as we go along. Inside, we just add each `value` to a sub-element indexed by `key`. The third argument `[]` is to set the initial value of the result to an empty array.

See https://eval.in/935015

(I'm assuming that the duplicate `x` keys in the question are a typo, and that the second is supposed to `z`, since that matches up with your suggested output)

Comment: Hello Iainn, sorry for the typo, i have corrected it. this solution works awesome, just that it makes $output['z'] and $output['y'] as array: ['f'], ['n'], rather than leaving them string.

Comment: splash58 solution seems to work the way its needed. However thanks to your answer, I got to know about `array_reduce` which seems to be really helpful function so +1 and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Learner Ah sorry, I didn't notice that you were keeping single elements as strings. Gildas's answer works best if did want to keep to a functional approach - that's pretty much what I should have done.

Answer (score 0):

For your original code you may find [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) interesting. I replaced the `continue`-s with `else`-s, but that is more like a matter of taste:

```
foreach($input as $in){
    extract($in);
    if(!empty($output[$key])){
        if(is_array($output[$key])){
            $output[$key][] = $value;
        } else {
            $output[$key] = [$output[$key],$value];
        }
    } else {
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
```

On a side note I would probably use two much simpler loops, one for building lists and another for extracting single elements:

```
foreach($input as $in){
    $output[$in['key']][] = $in['value'];
    /* or:  extract($in);
            $output[$key][]=$value; */
}
foreach($output as $key => $value){
    if(count($value)==1){
        $output[$key]=$value[0];
    }
}
```