# How to push key/value pair to array as separated element if key is already there?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

That`s all about easticsearch query logic... I need to send query with such array as this one:

```
`"query" => array:2 [▼
    "match" => array:2 [▼
      "location" => array:2 [▼
        "query" => "USA"
      ],
    "match" => array:2 [▼
      "car" => array:2 [▼
        "query" => "FORD"          ]
    ]
  ]`
```

The problem begins when we are trying to generate array with same keys:

```
   $rules['query'] = [];
   foreach ($field_value_array as $key => $value) {   
                    $match['match'][$key] = [
                      'query' => $value ]; 
                    $rules['query'] =  $match;
            }
```

PHP deletes them automatically and leave only last one. array_push function doesn't work in this situation.

You are last hope for me.

Comment: You couldn't have two `"match"` keys in the `"query"` array. Do you mean : `"query"=>[0=>['match'=>[...]],1=>['match'=>[...]]`?

Comment: Syscall is right. You can not have duplicated keys. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't have two `"match"` keys in the `"query"` array.

Then, you are missing `[]` to `$rules['query'] =  $match;`, so, the last value overrides the previous, and you will only get the last one.

Finally, you will get an extra "index" by using `['query' => $value ]`, you could use `$match['match'][$key]['query'] = $value;`.

You could try something like this:

```
$field_value_array=['location' => 'USA','cars' => 'FORD'];
$rules['query'] = [];
foreach ($field_value_array as $key => $value) {
    $match=[]; // reset $match to avoid duplicate keys
    $match['match'][$key]['query'] = $value;
    $rules['query'][] =  $match;
}
print_r($rules);
```

Will outputs:

```
Array (
    [query] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [match] => Array (
                            [location] => Array (
                                    [query] => USA
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [match] => Array (
                            [cars] => Array (
                                    [query] => FORD
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! But the biggest challenge is that elastic server accepts only mentioned structure. I guess they were thinking about js implementation of their API but its also impossible with json objects... 
If I`ll write this array manually it works:
`['match' => ['location' => ['query' => 'USA']],
  'match' => [ 'car' => ['query' => 'AUDI']],]
`
But I guess that its impossible  to generate such array with `foreach` :(
The worst variant is use `switch` but it`s not very good practice...

Comment: @VladislavPanin Thanks for your reply. Interesting. I think it's impossible to write a such array using PHP. `$data=['query'=>['match'=>['test'],'match'=>['test2']]]; print_r($data);` will outputs only one `match` key. How do you write it?

Comment: I've just sent it like it is... Anyway I found the way to make multiple fields filter work. But it is still mystical thing for me. Even `print_r` merge this array and gives only one unique key. So it's still opened question how do they read that array. I think the best way is write them and ask there developers... It`s very interesting :)