# Foreach loop array with same array name

Tags: php, foreach

What I am trying to do is this:
I want to echo information based on year/month/day.

My code is:

```
  $data = array(
    "2018" => array(
        "September" => array(
            "02" => array(
                "Line 1"
            ),
            "02" => array(
                "Line 11"
            ),
            "12" => array(
                "Line 2"
            ),
            "31" => array(
                "Line 3"
            )
        ),
        "December" => array(
            "02" => array(
                "Line 11"
            ),
            "12" => array(
                "Line 22"
            ),
            "31" => array(
                "Line 33"
            ),
            "32" => array(
                "Line 66"
            )
        )
    ),
    "2019" => array(
        "May" => array(
            "05" => array(
                "Line z"
            ),
            "15" => array(
                "Line y"
            ),
            "55" => array(
                "Line x"
            )
        )
    )
);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';

foreach ($data as $years => $year) {

    echo $years . "<br>";

    foreach ($year as $months => $month) {

        echo $months . "<br>";


        foreach ($month as $days => $day) {


            foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
                echo $days . " - " . $value . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see for 2018 september there are two arrays for the date of 2nd.
I was hoping to see this when print_r

```
2018
September
02 - Line 1
02 - Line 11
12 - Line 2
31 - Line 3
```

but instead I get this

```
2018
September
02 - Line 11
12 - Line 2
31 - Line 3
```

How can I echo both values of september 2, 2018?

Comment: You can't have two of the same key in an array, array keys are unique.

Comment: @Devon so what is the solution here? I am not really experienced with arrays.

Comment: Your structure is invalid,  you need to re-work it because your array can't exist as it is written.   You could possibly store Line 1 and Line 11 on September 02 in the same array but you can't have two keys of `02`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Associative Array Duplicate Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have duplicate keys. You are defining "02" twice.

Solution: Define "September" as:

```
    "September" => array(
        "02" => array(
            "Line 1",
            "Line 11"
        ),
        "12" => array(
            "Line 2"
        ),
        "31" => array(
            "Line 3"
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score -1):

[duplicate array name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK96N.png)

if you use **duplicate** array name, the last array be replaced in first array.