# Retrieve first key with array_search and same value

Tags: php, arrays, search

I need to retrieve the first key in array searched with array_search.

If I try this:

```
$a=array("Value3"=>"red","Value2"=>"green","Value3"=>"pink","Value4"=>"blue");
echo array_search("red",$a);
```

I receive a empty echo but expected: Value3

If I try this:

```
$a=array("Value3"=>"red","Value2"=>"green","Value3"=>"pink","Value4"=>"blue");
echo array_search("pink",$a);
```

I receive: Value3

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: each key in your associative array must be [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined Value3 twice in your array, so your array is actually contains
`array("Value2"=>"green","Value3"=>"pink","Value4"=>"blue");`

just change it to $a=array("**Value1**"=>"red","Value2"=>"green","Value3"=>"pink","Value4"=>"blue");

Comment: I can't change the Value. It's a translation function and occasionally use same key but different value.

I am looking to see if there is a method to display the first result found. Otherwise I will have to completely rewrite the function and the file I use as a dictionary.

Comment: If you have an array defined like `$a=array("Value3"=>"red","Value2"=>"green","Value3"=>"pink","Value4"=>"blue");` then php will simply delete the `"Value3"=>"red"` pair and you can't access it because it is not exists anymore

Comment: I agree with @RomanAzarov. `red` will be overwritten by `pink` and `red` will be no exist anymore in `$a` and the universal law is you cannot access which is not exist.